# Achar nomes(string) iguais em dois dataframes distintos e acrescentar uma coluna no segundo data frame com um outro dado do primeiro

Tags: python, data, for, range

Olá.

Tenho dois data frames:

**Times** com 629 linhas.

```
rank  prev_rank  name        league                 off def     spi  
0   1   1   Manchester City Barclays Premier League 3.34    0.24    95.24  
1   2   2   Liverpool   Barclays Premier League 2.95    0.28    92.96  
2   3   3   Bayern Munich   German Bundesliga   3.29    0.46    92.43  
3   4   4   Paris Saint-Germain French Ligue 1  2.88    0.47    89.55  
4   5   7   Real Madrid Spanish Primera Division    2.79    0.46    88.98  


**E partidas** com 27122 linhas.

date    league_id   league  team1   team2   spi1    spi2    prob1   prob2   probtie ... importance1 importance2 score1  score2  xg1 xg2 nsxg1   nsxg2   adj_score1  adj_score2  
0   2016-08-12  1843    French Ligue 1  Bastia  Paris Saint-Germain 51.16   85.68   0.0463  0.8380  0.1157  ... 32.4    67.7    0.0 1.0 0.97    0.63    0.43    0.45    0.00    1.05  
1   2016-08-12  1843    French Ligue 1  AS Monaco   Guingamp    68.85   56.48   0.5714  0.1669  0.2617  ... 53.7    22.9    2.0 2.0 2.45    0.77    1.75    0.42    2.10    2.10  
2   2016-08-13  2411    Barclays Premier League Hull City   Leicester City  53.57   66.81   0.3459  0.3621  0.2921  ... 38.1    22.2    2.0 1.0 0.85    2.77    0.17    1.25    2.10    1.05  
3   2016-08-13  2411    Barclays Premier League Crystal Palace  West Bromwich Albion    55.19   58.66   0.4214  0.2939  0.2847  ... 43.6    34.6    0.0 1.0 1.11    0.68    0.84    1.60    0.00    1.05  
4   2016-08-13  2411    Barclays Premier League Everton Tottenham Hotspur   68.02   73.25   0.3910  0.3401  0.2689  ... 31.9    48.0    1.0 1.0 0.73    1.11    0.88    1.81    1.05    1.05
```

Preciso comparar o nome do time (team1) do df2(partidas) com o name df1(times) e quando achar o correspondente adicionar em uma lista team_id[] o valor contido em "rank" no df1(times) e depois adicionar essa lista no df2 (partidas). Incluindo a nova variável "team1_id" no data frame 2.

E depois fazer o mesmo processo pro team2 gerando "team2_id".

Tentei de algumas formas e a última foi essa:

```py
team1_id = []
for i in range(0,27121):
    for n in range(0,628):
        if data['team1'].values[i] == times['name'].values[n]:
            team1_id.append(times['rank'][(n)])
```

Mas ele retornou somente 24647 valores mesmo não havendo valores em branco no team1 e todos existirem no outro df. E ao conferir os valores não estão ordenados corretamente, parece que a primeira linha não foi incluída.

```py
team2_id = []
for i in range(0,27121):
    for n in range(0,628):
        if data['team2'].values[i] == times['name'].values[n]:
            team2_id.append(times['rank'][(n)])
```

Esse está correto os primeiros registros verificados mais também com um número menor de registros que o esperado.

Comment: Tete usar a função merge: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar algo como:

```
def insert_rank2(df1, df2):
    if not 'rank' in df2.columns:
        df2['rank'] = pd.Series()
    for team in df1.name:
        index = df2[df2['team1'] ==  team].index
        df2.iloc[index]['rank'] = df1[df1['name'] == team]['rank'].values[0]
    return df2
```

Neste caso, você insere por índice o ranking onde os nomes dos times nas duas tabelas são os mesmos.
Além do código ficar menor, mais legível, fica mais rápida a execução.

Procure ao máximo, quando for trabalhar com DataFrame, trabalhar com lista (array) ou com cálculos matriciais (como fiz agora), pois ao invés de passar linha a linha, você insere (ou faz calculo) em bloco, o que reduz o tempo com bases grandes.

Comment: O código acima gerou a variável "rank" no df2 mais com todos os valores NaN.

Comment: O código continua dando problema? Na pequena amostra que você me mandou, ele funcionou bem.